# Server Manager.exe - .NET Framework Initialization Error

Tags: .net, azure-vm, servermanager, windows-server-2022

I'm using Azure VM with Windows Server 2022 Datacenter 21H2. Two weeks back, I created it, and from the end of last week, the server manager was not working. It gives an error.

" To run this application, you first must install one of the following versions of the .NET Framework: v4.0.30319

[image]

Then I tried to install the required .net version. Then I got the following message.

"Microsoft .NET Framework 4 is already a part of this operating system, but it is currently turned off.  To enable the .NET Framework 4, use Turn Windows features on or off in Control Panel."

[image]

Comment: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 Features might have been turned off/disabled in Windows Control Panel.
Go to Turn Windows Features on or off in the control panel. Uncheck .Net framework Advanced services and restart your computer. Install Microsoft .Net framework 4.0 once the restart is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx4 /All
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: I fixed the issue using this command. Thank you.